# Unable to put image adjanct to div

Tags: html, css

I have following HTML:

```css
 #details {
   padding-top: 2%;
 }
 #details #big_image {
   width: 400px;
   display: inline-block;
   background: darkred;
 }
 #details #big_text {
   display: inline-block;
 }
 #details #big_text span {
   display: block;
 }
 #details #big_text .title {
   font-weight: bold;
 }
 #details #big_text .description {
   width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div id="details">
  <div id="big_image">
    <img src="https://thejewishstar.files.wordpress.com/2009/02/red-apples.jpg" width="400" height="400" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div id="big_text">
    <span class="title">
                <h3>Apple</h3>
            </span>
    <span class="description">
                An Apple a Day Keeps doctor away.An Apple a Day Keeps doctor away.An Apple a Day Keeps doctor away.An Apple a Day Keeps doctor away.
            </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Adding more text in the description puts both the title and description in next line. I want to show the image and text in parallel.

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/nmf2p9vs/

Comment: By default "div" elements will take the 100% width of the parent element. Using float style element you can modify this. That's what making the problem in this case.

Comment: @nevermind Can you make your comment as an Answer? I slightly modified your code by changing `px` to `%`

Comment: @Volatil3, k, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
#details
{
    padding-top: 2%;
}

#details #big_image
{

    width: 400px;
    display:block;
    background: darkred;
    float:left;
}

#details #big_text
{
    display: block;
}
#details #big_text span
{
    display: block;
}
#details #big_text .title
{
    font-weight: bold;
}
#details #big_text .description
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nmf2p9vs/

I've used `display:block`, and `float:left` for image div.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this css sweets your needs :

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h71kq7L9/)**

```
#details
{
    padding-top: 2%;
}

#details #big_image
{

    width: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: darkred;
    float: left;
}

#details #big_text
{
    display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      width: 300px;
}
#details #big_text span
{
    display: block;
}
#details #big_text .title
{
    font-weight: bold;
}
#details #big_text .description
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your CSS to:

## CSS

```
    #details
{
    padding-top: 2%;
    width:100%;
    display: block;
    background: darkred;
}
#big_image
{

    width: 60%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: darkred;
    float: left;
}

#details #big_text
{
    display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      width: 40%;
}
#details #big_text span
{
    display: inline-block;
}
#details #big_text .title
{
    font-weight: bold;
}
#details #big_text .description
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is th [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h71kq7L9/1/).